# getting error - ERROR in app: Exception on [POST], while trying to send a request using python and postman

Tags: python, streamlit

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f2SdS.png)
facing this erroe please help anyone..

i have tried installing and reinstallig or upgdae to downgrade python module but same error.this app is connected in backend with a flask app.
Python script

```
@app.route('/chat', methods=['POST'])
def chat():
    inp = request.json['input']

    with open("intents.json") as file:
        data = json.load(file)

    # load trained model
    model = keras.models.load_model('chat_model')

    # load tokenizer object
    with open('tokenizer.pickle', 'rb') as handle:
        tokenizer = pickle.load(handle)

    # load label encoder object
    with open('label_encoder.pickle', 'rb') as enc:
        lbl_encoder = pickle.load(enc)

    # parameters
    max_len = 200
    
    while True:
        preprocessed_input = preprocess_text(inp)
        sequence = tokenizer.texts_to_sequences([preprocessed_input])
        padded_sequence = keras.preprocessing.sequence.pad_sequences(sequence, truncating='post', maxlen=max_len)
        result = model.predict(padded_sequence)
        tag = lbl_encoder.inverse_transform([np.argmax(result)])
        probability = np.max(result)

        for i in data['intents']:
            if (len(i['tags'])>0):
                if i['tags'][0] == tag:
                    response = {'response': i['answer'], 'score': str(probability)}
                    return response
```

Error

```
[2024-03-28 09:07:26,533] ERROR in app: Exception on /chat [POST]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Owner\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 2190, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
  File "C:\Users\Owner\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1486, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
  File "C:\Users\Owner\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1484, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.dispatch_request()
  File "C:\Users\Owner\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1469, in dispatch_request
    return self.ensure_sync(self.view_functions[rule.endpoint])(**view_args)
  File "c:\Users\Owner\Downloads\MedIQ-ChatBot-main\MedIQ-ChatBot-main\flask\main.py", line 36, in chat
    inp = request.json['input']
KeyError: 'input'
127.0.0.1 - - [28/Mar/2024 09:07:26] "POST /chat HTTP/1.1" 500 -``

    
i am getting this error
```

Comment: Have you considered given the error (`JSONDecodeError`) it might be helpful to see the relevant JSON file?  Additionally, please proofread your question for spelling and grammar, and format the error output correctly.